# Permission problem with php upload form

Tags: php, file-upload, permissions

I am trying to create a simple php image uploading form. I appear to have some kind of permissions problem though and I'm not sure how to fix this...

Here's my code...

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

upload_file.php...

```
<?php
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Here's the error I get...

Stored in: upload/81350042.jpgPHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/81350042.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\websites\tb123654\www\upload_file.php on line 27 PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\upload\php5BFB.tmp' to 'upload/81350042.jpg' in D:\websites\tb123654\www\upload_file.php on line 27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open your ftp client, right click on the folder you upload things to, attributes or propieties, set permission to 777.

or

> chmod 777 yourfolder

Comment: I get the message "Setting access properties failed"

Comment: do you own the server and have console access or just a ftp access? what ftp client are you using(if any)?

Comment: I just have ftp access in this case, though I have access to another server with console access. I am using Dreamweaver.

Comment: Try changing permission to the folder with an access panel like CPanel if your hosting provider give it to you, or try to use php http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: OK... Apparently due to the level of hosting I have on this account I am unable to change these settings myself, but they have done it for me and now it works. Your advice will certainly help on other hosting packages I have though so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no folder called "uploads" in "D:\websites\tb1234\www\" so the images can't be moved there. I think that's what your script is trying to do. Try to use absolute paths and see if that works.